# How to simulate object oriented programming with a procedural language?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, jobs

I have been asked this question on a job interview, so I would like to know it. How can we simulate object-oriented language with a procedural language, so that we complete all object-oriented programming concepts: Abstraction. Encapsulation. Inheritance. Polymorphism.

Thank you, guys!!! :)

Comment: *Could* be better suited for [Comp Sci](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at how people have taken procedural languages such as JavaScript and utilized the features to apply OO principles.

**Polymorphism:** Utilizes the prototype properties of an object.

**Abstraction and Inheritance** Composition of other objects in the Object's class, inheritance of objects with prototypes

**Encapsulation** Object types can define internal methods and functionality that external consuming objects do not need to understand to utilize.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript
- http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

Answer (score 1):

One aspect of it is that `object.method(params...)` is just syntactic sugar for `function(data, params...)`.  With the latter, the developer would have to discipline themselves not to pass in a pointer to the wrong kind of data or modify the data in any other way -- things that the compiler enforces for you in an OO language.

Comment: That's not true if `method` is a virtual function.

Comment: Well, it's arguably still true, just more complicated.  To simulate virtual functions, the procedural developer would have to concoct some scheme to determine which function to call at runtime, based on the actual type of the data.  An OO language takes care of all this for you.

Comment: You can implement OO using procedural code, but the amount of logic you would need to handle polymorphism would be a stretch for any reasonable definition of "syntactic sugar."